# ASP.NET Core, HTTPS and Custom Root CA

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, nginx, ssl

I've written a little proxy ASP.NET Core Web API app ([see here](https://github.com/mu88/JoplinAsustorMediator/)) that is running on my Raspberry Pi within a Linux Docker container. The app runs under `http://raspberry.fritz.box:5200/joplin` and forwards all requests to `https://nas.fritz.box:9815`.

Using [XCA](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/), I've created a custom Root CA and a HTTPS certificate for `nas.fritz.box`. I've successfully registered the custom Root CA certificate within my Raspberry Pi and `curl https://nas.fritz.box` works without any problems.

But within the Docker container, the TLS certificate validation fails. I assume that either Kestrel or the Docker container have their own certificate store.

So I'd like to achieve the following:

1. I can access my app via HTTPS (`https://raspberry.fritz.box:5200/joplin` instead of `http://raspberry.fritz.box:5200/joplin`) without certification validation errors.
2. Requests towards `https://nas.fritz.box:9815` do not fail within my app running in the Docker container.

I assume that the solution to both issues lies in providing the correct certificate(s). But I don't see the path: do I have to provide a single certificate only for `raspberry.fritz.box` with the complete certificate chain? Or two independent certificates (for `raspberry.fritz.box` and the custom Root CA)? And how to I have to configure it?

I've already read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0#secure-the-app), but I still don't get it.

For the sake of completeness: my app runs behind a reverse proxy (nginx) and will be accessed via `https://raspberry.fritz.box/joplin` in production, where nginx forwards all requests internally to `http://raspberry.fritz.box:5200/joplin`. Since I've configured both my custom Root CA and the HTTPS certificate for nginx on my Raspberry Pi, I can run `curl https://raspberry.fritz.box/joplin` from my production machine without any problem.